# Why is this code not correct for PySchools Topic 2 Q uestion 7?

Tags: python

That's my second post in 2 days about pyschools , i hope it's OK.
The exercise asks me to do the following: Write a function that uses a default value. 
It also gives me an example code which i have to improve in order to print out the correct output (like if the input is introduce('Lim', 20) , the output should be 'My name is Lim. I am 20 years old.' 
The code given by pyschool which i have to improve:

```
def introduce(name, age = 0):
    msg = "My name is %s. " % name
    if age == 0:
       msg += ""
    else:
       msg += ""
    return msg
```

My code:

```
def introduce(name, age=0):
    msg = "My name is %s. " % name
    if age == 0:
        msg += " My age is secret."
    else:
        msg += " I am %d years old." % age
    return msg
```

It returns the same answers as pyschools' code checker, but due to unclear reasons, the website says my answers are wrong. What might be the problem ?
I'm sorry if i didn't make myself clear enough and you don't understand what i'm trying to say. I have a hard time expressing myself as English is not my native language.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please rewrite your title to describe your problem or ask a clear question.

Comment: The problem could be that you have a blank space both at the end of the `name` format string, and also at the beginning of the other strings. Probably you just need one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. The only thing I can think of is that the output has two spaces in the middle. Try fixing that: `msg = "My name is %s." % name`

Comment: I just tried it on the site (after posting my comment). That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def introduce(name, age=0):
    msg = "My name is %s. " % name

    if age == 0:
       msg += "My age is secret."
    else:
       msg += "I am %s years old." % age
    return msg
```